# Javascript compression and the object properties issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, minify, google-closure-compiler, yui-compressor

The main JavaScript compressors and minifiers don't deal with object properties names. (Google Closure, YUI...)

I noticed there's a big difference in the resulting size (gzipped and don't gzipped) depending on which way or pattern we decide to choose for our script.

As an example, choosing the prototype pattern for our project will very probably generate bigger resulting files (uncompressed, compressed and gzipped).

Here's a little comparison with two portions of code doing exactly the same:

- [Prototype pattern](http://jsfiddle.net/imac/rgbku3a1/) **138 bytes** gzipped (286 bytes uncompressed)
- [Without pattern](http://jsfiddle.net/rgbku3a1/1/) **87 bytes** gzipped (110 bytes uncompressed)

Compressed using [Google Closure compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home).

The result is quite evident by just looking at the resulting compressed code:

**Prototype pattern**

---

> var MyBluePrint=function(){this.name="demo";this.someFunction=function(){alert("some function")};this.someOtherFunction=function(){alert("some other function")};this.showMyName=function(){alert(this.name)};this.someFunction();this.someOtherFunction();this.showMyName()};new MyBluePrint;

**Without pattern**

---

> var MyBluePrint=function(){alert("some function");alert("some other function");alert("demo")};new MyBluePrint;

Anything using object properties won't be compressed. Such as:

```
//function declarations
this.someFunction = function(){ ... }

//objects
var demo = {
    isActive: 'aaaa'.
    name: 'aaaa'
}
```

Should we be really thinking about this when creating our projects? 
It wouldn't be the first time where rather than having an object full of properties I decide to use normal variables just for the fact of compress long property names being used multiple times.

Comment: Depends on the potential savings, and therefore, the size of your code-to-be-minimized. How large would the final savings be?

Comment: Your JSFiddle links are identical. Both appear to be the "without pattern" method.

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth sorry for that. Updated link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Property names are fully re-nameable by Closure-Compiler using `ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS`. In addition, to get the full power of Closure-compiler, you need to tell the compiler that `MyBluePrint` is a constructor using the `@constructor` annotation. Also, what you call the "prototype pattern" is in fact using instance methods - not prototypes.

Here's updated comparisons:

- [Instance Methods](http://jsfiddle.net/rgbku3a1/5/) - 104 bytes gzipped
- [Private Closures](http://jsfiddle.net/rgbku3a1/6/) - 79 bytes gzipped
- [Prototype Methods](http://jsfiddle.net/rgbku3a1/4/) - 81 bytes gzipped

Closure compiler can completely inline methods in many cases making the output size differences almost negligible. If you can use Closure-compiler with `ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS`, you should choose the code pattern that provides the best maintainability and let the compiler handle the optimizations.

However all of these comparisons are basically meaningless. To have actual GZIP compression comparisons you need a large code base. Small snippets of code do not provide accurate representations.